# mysql query optimization within the same table

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

This following query is returning as a slow query under query monitor. It takes approx 0.4sec. Is there any way to improve its query speed?

Query under the same table (wp_postmeta), fetching 2 sets of meta_key and meta_value for its condition

```
SELECT p.post_id as id
FROM `wp_postmeta`as p, `wp_postmeta`as b
WHERE p.post_id = b.post_id
AND (b.meta_key = 'gift_price' and b.meta_value != '')
AND (p.meta_key = '_stock_status' and p.meta_value = 'instock')
```

I have tried to play with gift_price's meta_value > 1 and it actually slows it down even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "meta" tables in WP have an inefficient schema specification.  Recommendations:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score 0):

Index the wp_postmeta table

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` 
   ADD INDEX `IndexName` (`post_id` ASC, `meta_key` ASC, `meta_value` ASC);
```

Use EXPLAIN and check if the index is working

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p.post_id as id
FROM `wp_postmeta`as p, `wp_postmeta`as b
WHERE p.post_id = b.post_id
AND (b.meta_key = 'gift_price' and b.meta_value != '')
AND (p.meta_key = '_stock_status' and p.meta_value = 'instock')
```

Comment: `meta_value` may be a `LONGTEXT`, which cannot be in an index.